# DataTrans iOS library Registration failed / card data is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment

I'm trying to implement DataTrans iOS Library and I'm getting the following error:

> Error Domain=ch.datatrans.ios-payment Code=3 "Validation Error" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000459530 {Error Domain=DTNetworkingErrorDomain Code=2000 "access denied (XML alias service)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=access denied (XML alias service)}}, ch.datatrans.payment-method=VIS, NSLocalizedDescription=Validation Error}

This is what I've done so far according to the documentation:

```
NSArray* creditCards = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DTPaymentMethodVisa, DTPaymentMethodMasterCard,
                        DTPaymentMethodPostFinanceCard, nil];

DTPaymentRequest* paymentRequest = [[DTPaymentRequest alloc] init];
paymentRequest.amountInSmallestCurrencyUnit = 10000;
paymentRequest.localizedPriceDescription = @"123";
paymentRequest.currencyCode = @"CHF";
paymentRequest.merchantId = @"xxxxxx";
paymentRequest.refno = [ModelProfile singleton].shopCartNo;
paymentRequest.signature = @"xxxxxxx";

DTPaymentController* paymentController = [DTPaymentController
                                          paymentControllerWithDelegate:self
                                          paymentRequest:paymentRequest
                                          paymentMethods:creditCards];
paymentController.paymentOptions.showBackButtonOnFirstScreen = YES;
paymentController.paymentOptions.testing = YES;
[paymentController presentInNavigationController:self.navigationController animated:YES];
```

[image: DataTrans error example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting DataTrans i found the solution.
The problem was that my test merchant ID was configured for web transactions, so creating a new test merchant-ID for in-app transactions (iOS/Android libraries) solved my problem.